# Is there anyway to install a software inside a VM?

Tags: installation, virtual-machine, kvm-switch, remote-installation

In my system I have 100s of virtual machines and I want to install a package uniformly inside those VMs, same version etc. I may not have the passwords for those VMs, becuase different users may change the password for their VMs.

Using `qemu-guest-agent` we can do many things like fetching IP address of VM or ping VM etc. So can we install a package also using `qemu-guest-agent` or is there any other way to do the same ?

Comment: Well, the question you posted explains how to do that in the accepted answer.

Comment: @EBGreen They are using Windows based VMs and the tool is Windows specific.

Comment: You should probably clarify your question to exclude Windows then. What OS are the VMs built on? Regardless, the process is essentially the same. Identify the file changes, mount the VM, make the file changes. You just don't have to deal with the registry.

Comment: @EBGreen That solution in not reliable, its given in the answer.

Comment: You're right it isn't. It is still the best answer.

Comment: VM's wouldn't be of much use if you couldn't install software in them.  Is this a generic question about how to install software, or a special case, like the constraints described in the linked question?  Please be very specific about exactly what you're asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install a software without booting a VM](http://superuser.com/questions/650744/install-a-software-without-booting-a-vm)

Comment: That is a valid point. One simpler solution is to fire up the VM and run the installer.

Comment: @EBGreen I have edited the question.

Comment: If you can't get into the VM at all I wouldn't expect you to be able to install anything. Pretty pathetic security otherwise.

Comment: @EBGreen Though the case is different but using libgustfs we can make changes in the disk image, without even thinking of password.

Comment: Are there hundreds of physical machines?  Are all of the VMs Ubuntu?  Is a potential solution to provide an installer and instructions to each user and let them do it?

Comment: @fixer1234 Yeah there are 100s of VMs in the system and I want to give the same environment to each user. May be we can say to each user to install the package but for novice users it may be a problem.

Comment: Using libgustfs is essentially the solution in the linked question. You mount the VM and make the same changes that the installer would make.

Comment: Here is the best solution for this kind of problem. Its just the pointer, serach more about it. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/virt-customize.1.html